# Prove that $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are orthogonal vectors

Tags: vectors

The vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are given in terms of the basis vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ as follows:

$\vec{u} = 3\vec{a} + 3\vec{b} - \vec{c}$

$\vec{v} = \vec{a} + 2\vec{b} + 3\vec{c}$

I've tried $\vec{u}.\vec{v}$ to see if their dot product equals to 0, but it does not. Am I missing something?

It was given that $\vec{a}, \vec{b},$ and $\vec{c}$ form a basis in $R^3$.

It was also given that:

$|\vec{a}| = 1, |\vec{b}| = 2,|\vec{c}| = 3$

Comment: You need an orthonormal basis.

Comment: I have edited my post. Please have a look.

Comment: And, are $a, b, c$ pairwise orthogonal?

Comment: Yes it was also specified (a, b, c) is a right-handed triad. My fault for omitting what I thought were extra parts of the question.

Comment: What did you get when you computed the dot product?

Comment: (3)(1) + (3)(2) + (-1)(3) = 6.

Comment: You can’t just take the sum of products of coefficients like that: for the formula of the inner product to be the dot product like that, the basis must be orthonormal. Yours isn’t. The chirality doesn’t matter here because inner products don’t distinguish “left” from “right.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these changes, $\langle u,v\rangle = \langle 3a+3b-c, a+2b+3c\rangle
\stackrel{!}{=}\langle 3a,a\rangle +\langle 3b,2b\rangle +\langle -c,3c\rangle
= 3\langle a,a\rangle +6\langle b,b\rangle - 3\langle c,c\rangle
= 3\cdot 1^2+ 6\cdot 2^2-3\cdot 3^2 = 0$. But you still need that the basis is orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is typo regarding signs in $u$ and $v$

We assume an ortonormal basis .

The way we have it now the dot product is $$ 3|a|^2+6|b|^2-3|c|^2=6$$

If we change $u$ to $-3a+3b -c$ then we have orthogonality.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand $u\cdot v$ you find $9a\cdot b+8 a\cdot c+7b\cdot c$.
There is no reason for this to be zero in general, unless we also know that $a,b,c$ are orthogonal. So my guess is that in the instructions for the problem there was the information that $a,b,c$ are orthogonal.